# MySql J/Connector 5.1.39 not working when you use select ... order by

Tags: java, mysql

I've updated J/connector in my program from Connector 5.1.7 to Connector 5.1.39 and I saw selections stop working.

After digging more I realize that only ordered selects don't work. If I remove the `order by` from sql query everything is nice.

Here is my program

```
package test;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MysqlVersion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4&useSSL=false";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";

        try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from `scripts` order by id desc");

            //this returns false when order by is in the query
            System.out.println(rs.next());

        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(MysqlVersion.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } finally {

            try {

                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }

                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }

                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {

                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(MysqlVersion.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Always `System.out.println(rs.next());` will return false when '`order by`' is in query.
If I go back to earlier version everything works ok. Am I doing something wrong. Is there a special setup I need to do? Or this is a bug?

I'm using MySql 5.7.14

Comment: If the only thing you changed was upgrading the JDBC driver, then it sounds like a bug in the driver. Why don't you ask them and/or report it to them?